Getting HijrahDate month name in Android
I am trying to display formatted Islamic month name using Java, currently I have the following code:
HijrahDate date = HijrahDate.from(LocalDate.of(2024, 4, 11));
System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM", Locale.US).format(date));

When I run this code on a Windows computer with Java 11 (Temurin jdk-11.0.8.10-hotspot), I get the following result (which I assume is a correct one):

Shawwal

See that code run at Ideone.com using Java 12, giving same result.
However when I run the same code on an Android device, I get the following output (just a month number):
10

I tested it on various devices, for example Samsung Galaxy smartphone with Android 14, emulator with Android 13 and Rockchip RK3588 box with Android 12, but all of them give the same result, so I assume it is not just a one-device or one-manufacturer problem.
Is there a reliable way to get Islamic / Hijrah calendar month names on Android?

@BasilBourque For example Android 13 should support Java 11 API and core libraries, according to https://developer.android.com/build/jdks. And on my computer, even Oracle JDK 8 prints "Shawwal" (correct), not "10" (incorrect, as on Android)

I did not know Android had been upgraded to Java 11 levels of functionality. I'll delete my first Comment. But I do suspect your issue is related somehow to localization.

If Android doesn’t provide the month names you want, I suggest that the solution is that you code them into your app yourself.

Why the close vote, please? This question is perfectly clear. Which detail is missing?

I reported it to Android issue tracker as well, so far without any response: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/333981064

Here’s my demonstration of how to format Hijrah month names without relying on locale data of the device.
